# Given $f(x)=\frac{x-1}{x^2-x+1}$, find the largest interval of $x\in\Bbb R$ such that $f(x)$ is continuous on that interval

Tags: functions

What does "the largest interval" here mean? I do not understand this question. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Well, the function is continuous everywhere, so I guess the answer is $(-\infty, \infty)$? But I agree, the question is strangely written.

Answer (score 0):

The function is defined on the whole set of real number, so the largest interval is
$\color{red}{(-\infty, \infty)}$

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Let $D\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ be the "largest interval" on which the function $f$ is continuous. Note that if $f$ is continuous on $D$, then $f$ is also continuous on every subset $B\subseteq D$ of $D$. The word "largest interval" is used here in a sense that, if $f$ is continuous on any $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$, then we must have $A\subseteq D$.

Now, to find such an interval, we can argue as follows.

We first note that $x^2-x+1>0$ for every $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Thus the function $f$ is well defined for every $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

We have $$f(x)=\dfrac{g(x)}{h(x)}$$ for every $x\in\mathbb{R}$, where the functions $g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, $h:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ are defined by $g(x):=x-1$ and $h(x):=x^2-x+1$.

Let $x_0\in\mathbb{R}$. We have $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to x_0}g(x)=x_0-1$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to x_0}h(x)=x_0^2-x_0+1\neq 0$.

By the quotient rule for limits, we have $$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)=\displaystyle\lim_{x\to x_0}\dfrac{g(x)}{h(x)}=\dfrac{x_0-1}{x_0^2-x_0+1}$$

We therefore have $$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)=f(x_0)$$ and hence $f$ is continuous at $x_0$.

Since $x_0$ was arbitrary, the function $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$.

Now, if $f$ is continuous on any $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$, we have $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$. Thus the largest domain on which $f$ is continuous is $\mathbb{R}$.